# Find a formula for all of the points $(x,y)$ on the hyperbola $x^2 - 2y^2=1$ whose coordinates are rational numbers.

Tags: pythagorean-triples

I use the initial point as $(-1,0)$ ,then $y=m(x+1)$ and put the y in hyperbola, but I can't find a rational value of m.

Comment: You don't find rational value of $m$. Instead, for each rational value of $m$, you solve for $x$ and $y$ and you find solutions this way.

Comment: I get $(1-2m^2)x^2-4m^2x-(1+2m^2)=0$, get $x_1=-1$. As we know for $ax^2+bx+c=0, x_1+x_2=-b/a\ and\  x_1x_2=c/a$. So $x_2=(1+2m^2)/(1-2m^2)$, and put $x_2$ in $y=m(x+1)$ get $y=2m/(1-2m^2)$. Then, get $(x,y)=((1+2m^2)/(1-2m^2),2m/(1-2m^2))$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
1 &= x^2 - 2y^2  \\
  &= x^2 - 2(m(x+1))^2  \\
  &= (1-2m^2)x^2 - 4m^2 x-2 m^2  \text{.}
\end{align*}
If $m = 0$, $x = \pm 1$ (footnote 1), otherwise $x = \frac{-1-2m^2}{-1+2m^2}$ and then $y = \frac{x^2-1}{2} = \frac{\left( \frac{-1-2m^2}{-1+2m^2}\right)^2 - 1}{2} = \frac{4m^2}{(1-2m^2)^2}$.

(footnote 1):  We know $x = -1$ gives a rational point, but no choice of $m$ will give this point, so we have to call it out separately.